# rails new not starting and gem install pg not working

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I tried to create rails app by

```
rails new app-name --database=postgresql
```

This threw error for few gems like

```
An error occurred while installing pg
```

This was for few gems like `racc`, `byebug`. Even though I have all the pre-requisistes:

```
ruby -v
#ruby 3.0.0

rails -v
# rails 6.1.4.1
```

and could log into postgres by giving

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

I tried `bundle install` but the same issue persisted. So I decided to manually install every gem and started with `pg` gem.

When I run `sudo gem install pg` it gave

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf*****hp.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-file search libpq-fe.h
```

and got `/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h` but actually I don't have `/usr/include/postgresql`.

I tried few other commands like

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

They didn't throw any error but still `sudo gem install pg` was not working.

I tried all others solutions i could find on internet, so I'm not sure whether I have broken package or installed anything wrong or what went wrong. Thanks in advance for helping.